# How to assign multiple hook classes in TestRunner for Karate DSL?

Tags: java, karate

below is a snippet of my TestRunner.java, using Karate 1.4.0

```
...
  @Test
  public void testParallel() {
    Results results = Runner.path("classpath:")
        .tags("~@ignore")
        .outputCucumberJson(true)
        .outputJunitXml(true)
        .hook(new KarateHook())
        .hook(new AnotherHook())
        .parallel(4);

    generateReport(results.getReportDir());

    Assertions.assertThat(results.getFailCount())
    .withFailMessage(String.format("There are %s failing scenarios.", results.getFailCount()))
    .isZero();
        
  }
...
```

As you can see, I am using two hooks from different classes. The insides of `KarateHook()` and `AnotherHook()` looks like this (not the full content, hopefully enough to give context, can provide more if needed):

KarateHook.java :

```
...
  @Override
  public void afterScenario(ScenarioRuntime sr) {
    LOGGER.info("THIS IS DEFAULT afterScenario HOOK")
  }
...
```

AnotherHook.java :

```
...
  @Override
  public void afterScenario(ScenarioRuntime sr) {
    LOGGER.info("THIS IS THE OTHER afterScenario HOOK")
  }
...
```

My expectation when running the test with single `Scenario A` is:

```
<Scenario A ran and success>
- THIS IS DEFAULT afterScenario HOOK
- THIS IS THE OTHER afterScenario HOOK
```

Instead, I got this:

```
<Scenario A ran and success>
- THIS IS DEFAULT afterScenario HOOK
<Scenario A ran AGAIN and success>
- THIS IS THE OTHER afterScenario HOOK
```

I have tried to use `.hooks` instead of `.hook`:

```
@Test
public void testParallel() {
  List<RuntimeHook> karateHooks = new ArrayList<>();
  karateHooks.add(new KarateHook());
  karateHooks.add(new AnotherHook());
  Results results = Runner.path("classpath:")
      .tags("~@ignore")
      .outputCucumberJson(true)
      .outputJunitXml(true)
      .hooks(karateHooks)
      .parallel(4);
```

But the behavior is the same :(

What is the proper way to achieve what I expected above?

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: this could very well be a bug. do you think you can contribute code or follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Sorry, It turns out to be my own mistake. Let me explain.

Comment: My TestRunner class above is actually a class extending another BaseTestRunner class *and* triggering that BaseTestRunner inside TestRunner. So I was actually running the test two times :(

Comment: Btw, I'm new here, is there a way to mark my question as Answered/Solved/Invalid?

Comment: you can add an answer yourself to the question. after a period of 2 days I think you can mark it as "accepted" yourself